# Copying parameters from .env.dist to .env in php

Tags: php, file

I have file `.env.dist`

in `.env.dist` have:

```
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
DATABASE_NAME=db_name
```

How i should from `.env.dist` create `.env`(copy)?

Comment: Use any text editor and rename the file into .env along with any credentials you need to change according to your server.

Comment: That's just a text file with a different name. You can copy the file (like you would any other file in your OS) and rename it to what you want. Then open the new file and edit what you need to edit. Or you could create a new text file and call it `.env`, open it and copy the contents of `.env.dist` into the new file, and edit what you need to edit. This isn't really a programming question, it's more of a "computer 101" type of question. Unless you actually mean something different?

Comment: Shell line something like `cp .env.dist .env` should do it. Then edit the new file with your settings.